# Why does 100 ~~ ^100 return false in Perl 6?

Tags: raku

`perl6 -e '100 ~~ ^100'` returns `False`, where it looks like to me it should return `True`, as 100 is in the range between 0 and 100. Is this a part of the design of the `Range` class that I'm just not understanding here or is this a bug?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The syntax `^100` is short-hand for `0 ..^ 100` and the `^` means "excluding". `0 ..^ 100` is actually the numbers 0 through 99. That's because with `^100` you get a list with exactly 100 elements - which is very useful for `for` loops.

Don't forget you can output the whole list with `say (^100).list`.

In addition to that, there's also `^..` and `^..^` which exclude the first element or the first and last element.

Comment: Ah, I thought the shortcut did `0..100`.

Answer (score 5):

The caret `^` indicates that the endpoint is excluded from the range, so 100 is actually not included.

`perl6 -e '100 ~~ 100'` will return `true`.

Read as: part of the design, cf. https://doc.perl6.org/type/Range